# Command-line to show a file's properties?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to write an app that displays the default Windows Properties sheet, I can't find much info on doing it the normal programmatic way, so I'm thinking maybe shell out to a command-line call; does anyone know the Windows command-line to call up a file's property/details window? Not having any luck searching for it.

This window here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that there *IS* no direct command-line call that can do this, so I whipped up a quick little VBScript to do it, since it appeared to be the quickest and easiest way to achieve the end result (at least for my specific need).

The VBScript simply sends the Windows Shortcut `Alt + Enter`; so, when a file is highlighted it'll automatically use that file as the one to send the shortcut to.

For anyone else who may want to do the same, just paste the following into a new text file and save it as a `.vbs` file:

`Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "%{ENTER}"`

For anyone interested in an even better solution, I ended up writing a small command-line app in VB.NET to do this, here's a link to it's full info + the source code: https://geekdrop.com/x/props

Comment: This answer should be just https://geekdrop.com/content/geekdrop-props-command-line-windows-property-sheet-opener

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense, there are two methods for going about this.  How you specifically accomplish it (i.e. PowerShell, C#, etc) is up to you.

1. Call the `ShellExecute` function on the file with the `PROPERTIES` verb.
2. Call the `SHObjectProperties` function on the file.

Examples of both can be found here in AutoIt: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/118673-open-a-files-properties-window/